# How to set individual state of child component which is added through loop in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a Parent react component where i am iterating a list of "tasks" using map function. Inside this function i am calling Child component to render(Passing each "taskId" as props).

Inside the Child component, i am calling redux to return the chart data based on the "taskId" from the parent props to rendering the chart.

I was expecting all the child component will return different chart but i am getting same chart in all of the child component.

How to set individual chart data/state of my child component?

If chart data cannot be retrieved inside the child, then how to do it in parent and pass it to child?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getTasks(id);
      }

      render() {
            {this.state.tasks && this.state.tasks.length > 0
                  ? this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => {
                        <Child key={task.id} taskId={task.id}>
                  }) : ""
            }
      }

      const mapStateToProps = state => ({
            tasks: state.task.get("tasks")
        });

      const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        getTasks: id => dispatch(taskOperations.getTasks(id))
      });

}


class Child extends React.Component{
      componentDidMount() {
         let taskId = this.props.taskId
         this.props.getChartData(taskId)
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
         // Anything to do here?
      }

      render() {
            // Showing same chart data for every child
            {this.props.chartData &&
            <Chart
                  options={this.props.chartData.options}
                  series={this.props.chartData.series}
                  type="line"
                  height={255}
            />
            }
      }

      const mapStateToProps = state => ({
            chartData: state.chart.get("chartData")
        });

      const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
             getChartData: id => dispatch(chartOperations.getChartData(id))
      });

}
```

Comment: I assume, you are writing chart data to same reducer, which means you are overwriting your data with latest response.